# Tkinter - columnspan doesn't seem to affect Message

Tags: python, tkinter

I've trying to create a simple interface in Python (2.7) with Tkinter featuring a user-input box, browse button and description on the first row and a multi-line explanation spanning their width on the line below.

My issue is that the `columnspan` option doesn't seem to allow my `Message` widget to span the width of the three columns above, as can be seen below:

[image: Non-spanning message box]

How can I get this `Message` to span the entire width? I've additionally tried using the `width` parameter but this seems to be of a different scale to that for the `Entry` widget.

My code is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.grid(sticky=N + W + E + S)

        # set up labels and buttons
        self.folder_text = Label(
            self, text='Select Folder:  ', font='Arial 10', anchor=W
        )
        self.folder_text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.input_folder = Entry(
            self, width=40, font='Arial 10'
        )
        self.input_folder.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.browse_button = Button(
            self, text="Browse", font='Arial 8 bold',
            command=lambda: self.browse_for_folder(self.input_folder)
        )
        self.browse_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.desc = Message(
            self, text='This tool will create a .csv file in the specified folder containing the Time and '
                       'Latitude/Longitude (WGS84) for all TIFF, RAW and JPEG/JPG files contained in the '
                       'folder with this information available.', font='Arial 8', anchor=W
        )
        self.desc.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky=E + W)

        self.run_button = Button(
            self, text="Run!", font='Arial 10 bold', fg='red',
            command=lambda: self.run(self.input_folder)
        )

        self.run_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

# ---SNIP---

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.destroy())
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.title('Get photo geolocations')

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @MichelTouw it's a [built-in widget type](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/message.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the background color of the widget you will see that it does indeed span multiple columns.

The main feature of the `Message` widget is that it will insert linebreaks in the text so that the text maintains a specific aspect ratio if a width is not specified. The text of a `Message` window will not fill extra horizontal space if the widget is made wider than its natural size.

The aspect ratio is ignored if you specify the width. Unlike the `Label` where the width refers to the number of characters, the `width` option of a `Message` is pixel-based (or distance: inches, centimeters, millimeters, or printer points).

A simple way to use the `width` option is to bind to the `<Configure>` event of the widget, and set the width option to be the actual width of the widget (or the width minus a little for a margin)

For example:

```
self.desc.bind("<Configure>", 
    lambda event: event.widget.configure(width=event.width-8))
```

Comment: This works exactly how I need it to, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `Message` uses an aspect ratio or a character width to determine its size.

You can give it a width and then it will work:

```
    self.desc = Message(
        self, text='This tool will create a .csv file in the specified folder containing the Time and '
                   'Latitude/Longitude (WGS84) for all TIFF, RAW and JPEG/JPG files contained in the '
                   'folder with this information available.', font='Arial 8', anchor=W, width = 400
    )
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can render the window, read out its width with `root.geometry()`, set the width on the widget, then set the text into it.